# SAS regex string

Tags: regex, sas, pcre

I have a question on the below code.
Where it has \s\S\S$, is this looking for something like: " NJ$"? I have not seen \S$. Unless, this is an actual dollar sign in the string.

Also, in the ^.*(\s\S\S$).*$/$1. Is this looking at beginning of string for something like: " NJ$"? I'm not sure what the .*$/$1 is doing. I am new to regex in SAS.

```
    if prxmatch('/\s\S\S$/',strip(claim_txn_merchant_clean)) then 
            do;
                claim_state = strip(prxchange('s/^.*(\s\S\S$).*$/$1/',-1,strip(claim_txn_merchant_clean)));
                claim_txn_merchant_clean = prxchange('s/\s\S\S$/$1/',-1,strip(claim_txn_merchant_clean));
            end;
```

Comment: `'s/^.*(\s\S\S$).*$/$1/'` is a Perl-like replacement command that removes all but the last two non-whitespace chars. `$1` is the RHS, the replacement placeholder that stores the last whitespace + 2 consecutive non-whitespace chars captured with `(\s\S\S)`

Comment: The `perl` tag is not valid here as SAS uses PCRE regex library.

Comment: @Wiktor: So add the PCRE tag!